# check if the image link is valid or not with php

Tags: php, curl, broken-links, broken-image

I have huge list of 45000+ image links in my database.
I need to test which of do not point to a image file (broken).

I have tried file_exists, cURL, header etc.
but all returned same result for both url (which has file and which dosen't)

here are the two links to test

[link1(correct)](http://visualez.com/uploadtile/tiles/combined/Grey%20serpegenti_307_140_NaturalGlossy_Ceratec%20Marble.jpg)

[link2(broken)](http://visualez.com/uploadtile/tiles/combined/Grey%20serpegenti_307_140_2NaturalGlossy_Ceratec%20Marble.jpg)

i need a php script to different all the links into broken or correct.

thanks... please help me.

Comment: To ask an On Topic question, please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)
 **We are very willing to help you fix your code, but we dont write code for you**

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can check html header to not to be 404 with requesting tools like Curl.

Comment: checked, but both the links results in broken.

Answer (score 1):

If you file is not on your filesystem you have to check the header of the file is found on the target system. You can do that with curl for example:

```
$handle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$response = curl_exec($handle);

/* Check for 404. */
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if($httpCode == 404) {
    /* Do something if the file is not found */
}

curl_close($handle);
```

Comment: image files are in my filesystem.